# Document contains at least one immense term in field=“errormsg.keyword” (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766

Tags: elasticsearch

i get this error when logstash try to write in elasticsearch.it create the index but there is no data available on elasticsearch.

```
Document contains at least one immense term in field="errormsg.keyword" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766
```

this is my pipeline.conf.

```
input {
        file {
        path => "c:/logstash.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline {
         pattern => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
         negate => true
         what => "previous"
   }
        }

}
filter {
grok{
      match => { "message" => "%{TIME:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:LEVEL} %{GREEDYDATA:errormsg}" }
    }
}
output {
if  "ERROR" in [LEVEL]
{
elasticsearch {
  hosts=>"localhost:9200"
  }
  }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

---Output of curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash/_mapping

```
    {
logstash-2017.06.16: {
mappings: {
_default_: {
_all: {
enabled: true,
norms: false
},
dynamic_templates: [
{
message_field: {
path_match: "message",
match_mapping_type: "string",
mapping: {
norms: false,
type: "text"}}},
{
string_fields: {
match: "*",
match_mapping_type: "string",
mapping: {
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword"}},
norms: false,
type: "text"}}}],
properties: {
@timestamp: {
type: "date",
include_in_all: false},
@version: {
type: "keyword",
include_in_all: false},
geoip: {
dynamic: "true",
properties: {
ip: {type: "ip"},
latitude: {
type: "half_float"},
location: {
type: "geo_point"},
longitude: {type: "half_float"}}}}},
logs: {
_all: {
enabled: true,
norms: false},
dynamic_templates: [
{message_field: {
path_match: "message",
match_mapping_type: "string",
mapping: {norms: false,type: "text"}}},
{string_fields: {
match: "*",match_mapping_type: "string",
mapping: {
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword"}},
norms: false,
type: "text"}}}],
properties: {
@timestamp: {
type: "date",
include_in_all: false},
@version: {
type: "keyword",
include_in_all: false},
LEVEL: {
type: "text",
norms: false,
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword"}}},
errormsg: {
type: "text",norms: false,
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword"}}},
geoip: {dynamic: "true",
properties: {
ip: {type: "ip"},
latitude: {type: "half_float"},
location: {type: "geo_point"},
longitude: {type: "half_float"}}},
host: {type: "text",norms: false,
fields: {
keyword: {type: "keyword"}}},
message: {type: "text",norms: false},
path: {type: "text",norms: false,
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword"}}},
tags: {type: "text",norms: false,
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword"}}},
timestamp: {type: "text",norms: false,
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword"}}}}}}}}
```

and this is for example the error to parse:

```
17:37:17,103 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web] Servlet.service()java.io.FileNotFoundException:
at org.thymeleaf.templateresource.ServletContextTemplateResource
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.
17:37:17,104 ERROR.....
```

thank you so much for your help @xeraa

Comment: Yes, keywords have this limit. I assume your LEVEL is too long? What's the rubydebug output there?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="errormsg.keyword" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[91, 111, 114, 103, 46, 97, 112, 97, 99, 104, 101, 46, 99, 97, 116, 97, 108, 105, 110, 97, 46, 99, 111, 114, 101, 46, 67, 111, 110, 116]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 78726.---I think i should change the field errormsg to be only text ---how can i do it--thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes. I think your only option is to set the following option in the Elasticsearch mapping of that field: `ignore_above = 256` (or whatever is a sensible value there). But I would assume something is wrong in your match — you probably didn't intend to have a huge keyword.

Comment: I want to match a trace exception like that '17:37:17,103 ERROR INF/view/security/accessDenied.html" does not exist at org.thymeleaf.templateresource.ServletContextTemplateResource.reader(ServletContextTemplateResource.java:95) [thymeleaf-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getId(Book.java:22).' --where i should put the option ignore_above = 256.---thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Ok, the parsing looks correct (you can also try it out on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). Then I assume your mapping is wrong. Please add output of the following query to your original question: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash/_mapping`. Also please add the exception to the question for better readability. Comments are very hard to follow.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Yes i tested by grokdebug and is correct.but the probleme in mapping.Please check the output in this link [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3RzVThvEyfTdnFBbkdVTlk5bzQ/view?usp=sharing].the text is long,i couldn't parse it here. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add the output (and the expection you are trying to parse) into the original question. That's what makes Stackoverflow easy to read and helpful for everyone.

Comment: I addes the output and the text to parse.thanks a lot.